# modal class not working on buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, modal-dialog

I have this form.

```
<form action="../massmail.php" method="post">
    <label>Periode:</label>
    <div class="form-inline"><input class="form-inline input-small" name="maand" type="text" placeholder="bijv.: juni" /> 
         <input class="input-mini" name="jaar" type="text" value="2015" />
    </div>
    <br /> <label>Inleidende tekst:</label>
    <div>
        <textarea name="inleiding" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    <br /> <label>url van de nieuwsbrief:</label>
    <div>
        <input class="input-xxlarge" name="link" type="url" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Verzenden</button>
        <button class="btn" formaction="../voorbeeld.php" formmethod="get" type="submit">Voorbeeld</button> 
        <a href="index.php"> <button class="btn" type="button">Annuleren</button> </a></div>
</form>
```

In the last `<div>` are the form controlls. The second button is what I want to change. It submits the form, overriding the default form action and gives a preview of what would be sent if the actual submit button (Verzenden) is pressed.

This all works, but I want to give this preview in a modal window (pop up). For some reason the modal class only works for `<a>` elements. I have previously solved this by setting the `<a>` element class to `btn modal`, but in this case I need the `formaction` so I need an actual button.

Things I have tried and results.

```
<button class="btn modal" formaction="../voorbeeld.php" formmethod="get" type="submit" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 920, y: 530}}">Voorbeeld</button>
```

Result: Form get's handled the way I expect, but no popup, results just get displayed as if a link is opened to the php page.

```
<a class="modal" href="voorbeeld.php" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 920, y: 530}}"> <button class="btn" type="button" formaction="../voorbeeld.php" formmethod="get" type="submit">Voorbeeld MOD</button> </a>
```

Result: This opens the popup with the php page, but the results from the form don't get through to the php page.

Included as snippet is the modal.css, which doesn't seem to have anything `<a>` or `<button>` specific. modal.js is the javascript, but I'm not really familiar with that.

I'm doing all of this in a custom html module in Joomla! 3.4.3.

Any help would be appreciated

```js
/*
  MIT-style license
 @author  Harald Kirschner <mail [at] digitarald.de>
 @author  Rouven Weßling <me [at] rouvenwessling.de>
 @copyright Author
*/
var SqueezeBox = {
  presets: {
    onOpen: function() {},
    onClose: function() {},
    onUpdate: function() {},
    onResize: function() {},
    onMove: function() {},
    onShow: function() {},
    onHide: function() {},
    size: {
      x: 600,
      y: 450
    },
    sizeLoading: {
      x: 200,
      y: 150
    },
    marginInner: {
      x: 20,
      y: 20
    },
    marginImage: {
      x: 50,
      y: 75
    },
    handler: false,
    target: null,
    closable: true,
    closeBtn: true,
    zIndex: 65555,
    overlayOpacity: .7,
    classWindow: "",
    classOverlay: "",
    overlayFx: {},
    resizeFx: {},
    contentFx: {},
    parse: false,
    parseSecure: false,
    shadow: true,
    overlay: true,
    document: null,
    ajaxOptions: {}
  },
  initialize: function(e) {
    if (this.options) return this;
    this.presets = Object.merge(this.presets, e);
    this.doc = this.presets.document || document;
    this.options = {};
    this.setOptions(this.presets).build();
    this.bound = {
      window: this.reposition.bind(this, [null]),
      scroll: this.checkTarget.bind(this),
      close: this.close.bind(this),
      key: this.onKey.bind(this)
    };
    this.isOpen = this.isLoading = false;
    return this
  },
  build: function() {
    this.overlay = new Element("div", {
      id: "sbox-overlay",
      "aria-hidden": "true",
      styles: {
        zIndex: this.options.zIndex
      },
      tabindex: -1
    });
    this.win = new Element("div", {
      id: "sbox-window",
      role: "dialog",
      "aria-hidden": "true",
      styles: {
        zIndex: this.options.zIndex + 2
      }
    });
    if (this.options.shadow) {
      if (Browser.chrome || Browser.safari && Browser.version >= 3 || Browser.opera && Browser.version >= 10.5 || Browser.firefox && Browser.version >= 3.5 || Browser.ie && Browser.version >= 9) {
        this.win.addClass("shadow")
      } else if (!Browser.ie6) {
        var e = (new Element("div", {
          "class": "sbox-bg-wrap"
        })).inject(this.win);
        var t = function(e) {
          this.overlay.fireEvent("click", [e])
        }.bind(this);
        ["n", "ne", "e", "se", "s", "sw", "w", "nw"].each(function(n) {
          (new Element("div", {
            "class": "sbox-bg sbox-bg-" + n
          })).inject(e).addEvent("click", t)
        })
      }
    }
    this.content = (new Element("div", {
      id: "sbox-content"
    })).inject(this.win);
    this.closeBtn = (new Element("a", {
      id: "sbox-btn-close",
      href: "#",
      role: "button"
    })).inject(this.win);
    this.closeBtn.setProperty("aria-controls", "sbox-window");
    this.fx = {
      overlay: (new Fx.Tween(this.overlay, Object.merge({
        property: "opacity",
        onStart: Events.prototype.clearChain,
        duration: 250,
        link: "cancel"
      }, this.options.overlayFx))).set(0),
      win: new Fx.Morph(this.win, Object.merge({
        onStart: Events.prototype.clearChain,
        unit: "px",
        duration: 750,
        transition: Fx.Transitions.Quint.easeOut,
        link: "cancel",
        unit: "px"
      }, this.options.resizeFx)),
      content: (new Fx.Tween(this.content, Object.merge({
        property: "opacity",
        duration: 250,
        link: "cancel"
      }, this.options.contentFx))).set(0)
    };
    document.id(this.doc.body).adopt(this.overlay, this.win)
  },
  assign: function(e, t) {
    return (document.id(e) || $$(e)).addEvent("click", function() {
      return !SqueezeBox.fromElement(this, t)
    })
  },
  open: function(e, t) {
    this.initialize();
    if (this.element != null) this.trash();
    this.element = document.id(e) || false;
    this.setOptions(Object.merge(this.presets, t || {}));
    if (this.element && this.options.parse) {
      var n = this.element.getProperty(this.options.parse);
      if (n && (n = JSON.decode(n, this.options.parseSecure))) this.setOptions(n)
    }
    this.url = (this.element ? this.element.get("href") : e) || this.options.url || "";
    this.assignOptions();
    var r = r || this.options.handler;
    if (r) return this.setContent(r, this.parsers[r].call(this, true));
    var i = false;
    return this.parsers.some(function(e, t) {
      var n = e.call(this);
      if (n) {
        i = this.setContent(t, n);
        return true
      }
      return false
    }, this)
  },
  fromElement: function(e, t) {
    return this.open(e, t)
  },
  assignOptions: function() {
    this.overlay.addClass(this.options.classOverlay);
    this.win.addClass(this.options.classWindow)
  },
  close: function(e) {
    var t = typeOf(e) == "domevent";
    if (t) e.stop();
    if (!this.isOpen || t && !Function.from(this.options.closable).call(this, e)) return this;
    this.fx.overlay.start(0).chain(this.toggleOverlay.bind(this));
    this.win.setProperty("aria-hidden", "true");
    this.fireEvent("onClose", [this.content]);
    this.trash();
    this.toggleListeners();
    this.isOpen = false;
    return this
  },
  trash: function() {
    this.element = this.asset = null;
    this.content.empty();
    this.options = {};
    this.removeEvents().setOptions(this.presets).callChain()
  },
  onError: function() {
    this.asset = null;
    this.setContent("string", this.options.errorMsg || "An error occurred")
  },
  setContent: function(e, t) {
    if (!this.handlers[e]) return false;
    this.content.className = "sbox-content-" + e;
    this.applyTimer = this.applyContent.delay(this.fx.overlay.options.duration, this, this.handlers[e].call(this, t));
    if (this.overlay.retrieve("opacity")) return this;
    this.toggleOverlay(true);
    this.fx.overlay.start(this.options.overlayOpacity);
    return this.reposition()
  },
  applyContent: function(e, t) {
    if (!this.isOpen && !this.applyTimer) return;
    this.applyTimer = clearTimeout(this.applyTimer);
    this.hideContent();
    if (!e) {
      this.toggleLoading(true)
    } else {
      if (this.isLoading) this.toggleLoading(false);
      this.fireEvent("onUpdate", [this.content], 20)
    } if (e) {
      if (["string", "array"].contains(typeOf(e))) {
        this.content.set("html", e)
      } else {
        this.content.adopt(e)
      }
    }
    this.callChain();
    if (!this.isOpen) {
      this.toggleListeners(true);
      this.resize(t, true);
      this.isOpen = true;
      this.win.setProperty("aria-hidden", "false");
      this.fireEvent("onOpen", [this.content])
    } else {
      this.resize(t)
    }
  },
  resize: function(e, t) {
    this.showTimer = clearTimeout(this.showTimer || null);
    var n = this.doc.getSize(),
      r = this.doc.getScroll();
    this.size = Object.merge(this.isLoading ? this.options.sizeLoading : this.options.size, e);
    var i = self.getSize();
    if (this.size.x == i.x) {
      this.size.y = this.size.y - 50;
      this.size.x = this.size.x - 20
    }
    if (n.x > 979) {
      var s = {
        width: this.size.x,
        height: this.size.y,
        left: (r.x + (n.x - this.size.x - this.options.marginInner.x) / 2).toInt(),
        top: (r.y + (n.y - this.size.y - this.options.marginInner.y) / 2).toInt()
      }
    } else {
      var s = {
        width: n.x - 40,
        height: n.y,
        left: (r.x + 10).toInt(),
        top: (r.y + 20).toInt()
      }
    }
    this.hideContent();
    if (!t) {
      this.fx.win.start(s).chain(this.showContent.bind(this))
    } else {
      this.win.setStyles(s);
      this.showTimer = this.showContent.delay(50, this)
    }
    return this.reposition()
  },
  toggleListeners: function(e) {
    var t = e ? "addEvent" : "removeEvent";
    this.closeBtn[t]("click", this.bound.close);
    this.overlay[t]("click", this.bound.close);
    this.doc[t]("keydown", this.bound.key)[t]("mousewheel", this.bound.scroll);
    this.doc.getWindow()[t]("resize", this.bound.window)[t]("scroll", this.bound.window)
  },
  toggleLoading: function(e) {
    this.isLoading = e;
    this.win[e ? "addClass" : "removeClass"]("sbox-loading");
    if (e) {
      this.win.setProperty("aria-busy", e);
      this.fireEvent("onLoading", [this.win])
    }
  },
  toggleOverlay: function(e) {
    if (this.options.overlay) {
      var t = this.doc.getSize().x;
      this.overlay.set("aria-hidden", e ? "false" : "true");
      this.doc.body[e ? "addClass" : "removeClass"]("body-overlayed");
      if (e) {
        this.scrollOffset = this.doc.getWindow().getSize().x - t
      } else {
        this.doc.body.setStyle("margin-right", "")
      }
    }
  },
  showContent: function() {
    if (this.content.get("opacity")) this.fireEvent("onShow", [this.win]);
    this.fx.content.start(1)
  },
  hideContent: function() {
    if (!this.content.get("opacity")) this.fireEvent("onHide", [this.win]);
    this.fx.content.cancel().set(0)
  },
  onKey: function(e) {
    switch (e.key) {
      case "esc":
        this.close(e);
      case "up":
      case "down":
        return false
    }
  },
  checkTarget: function(e) {
    return e.target !== this.content && this.content.contains(e.target)
  },
  reposition: function() {
    var e = this.doc.getSize(),
      t = this.doc.getScroll(),
      n = this.doc.getScrollSize();
    var r = this.overlay.getStyles("height");
    var i = parseInt(r.height);
    if (n.y > i && e.y >= i) {
      this.overlay.setStyles({
        width: n.x + "px",
        height: n.y + "px"
      });
      this.win.setStyles({
        left: (t.x + (e.x - this.win.offsetWidth) / 2 - this.scrollOffset).toInt() + "px",
        top: (t.y + (e.y - this.win.offsetHeight) / 2).toInt() + "px"
      })
    }
    return this.fireEvent("onMove", [this.overlay, this.win])
  },
  removeEvents: function(e) {
    if (!this.$events) return this;
    if (!e) this.$events = null;
    else if (this.$events[e]) this.$events[e] = null;
    return this
  },
  extend: function(e) {
    return Object.append(this, e)
  },
  handlers: new Hash,
  parsers: new Hash
};
SqueezeBox.extend(new Events(function() {})).extend(new Options(function() {})).extend(new Chain(function() {}));
SqueezeBox.parsers.extend({
  image: function(e) {
    return e || /\.(?:jpg|png|gif)$/i.test(this.url) ? this.url : false
  },
  clone: function(e) {
    if (document.id(this.options.target)) return document.id(this.options.target);
    if (this.element && !this.element.parentNode) return this.element;
    var t = this.url.match(/#([\w-]+)$/);
    return t ? document.id(t[1]) : e ? this.element : false
  },
  ajax: function(e) {
    return e || this.url && !/^(?:javascript|#)/i.test(this.url) ? this.url : false
  },
  iframe: function(e) {
    return e || this.url ? this.url : false
  },
  string: function(e) {
    return true
  }
});
SqueezeBox.handlers.extend({
  image: function(e) {
    var t, n = new Image;
    this.asset = null;
    n.onload = n.onabort = n.onerror = function() {
      n.onload = n.onabort = n.onerror = null;
      if (!n.width) {
        this.onError.delay(10, this);
        return
      }
      var e = this.doc.getSize();
      e.x -= this.options.marginImage.x;
      e.y -= this.options.marginImage.y;
      t = {
        x: n.width,
        y: n.height
      };
      for (var r = 2; r--;) {
        if (t.x > e.x) {
          t.y *= e.x / t.x;
          t.x = e.x
        } else if (t.y > e.y) {
          t.x *= e.y / t.y;
          t.y = e.y
        }
      }
      t.x = t.x.toInt();
      t.y = t.y.toInt();
      this.asset = document.id(n);
      n = null;
      this.asset.width = t.x;
      this.asset.height = t.y;
      this.applyContent(this.asset, t)
    }.bind(this);
    n.src = e;
    if (n && n.onload && n.complete) n.onload();
    return this.asset ? [this.asset, t] : null
  },
  clone: function(e) {
    if (e) return e.clone();
    return this.onError()
  },
  adopt: function(e) {
    if (e) return e;
    return this.onError()
  },
  ajax: function(e) {
    var t = this.options.ajaxOptions || {};
    this.asset = (new Request.HTML(Object.merge({
      method: "get",
      evalScripts: false
    }, this.options.ajaxOptions))).addEvents({
      onSuccess: function(e) {
        this.applyContent(e);
        if (t.evalScripts !== null && !t.evalScripts) Browser.exec(this.asset.response.javascript);
        this.fireEvent("onAjax", [e, this.asset]);
        this.asset = null
      }.bind(this),
      onFailure: this.onError.bind(this)
    });
    this.asset.send.delay(10, this.asset, [{
      url: e
    }])
  },
  iframe: function(e) {
    var t = this.doc.getSize();
    if (t.x > 979) {
      var n = this.options.size.x;
      var r = this.options.size.y
    } else {
      var n = t.x;
      var r = t.y - 50
    }
    this.asset = new Element("iframe", Object.merge({
      src: e,
      frameBorder: 0,
      width: n,
      height: r
    }, this.options.iframeOptions));
    if (this.options.iframePreload) {
      this.asset.addEvent("load", function() {
        this.applyContent(this.asset.setStyle("display", ""))
      }.bind(this));
      this.asset.setStyle("display", "none").inject(this.content);
      return false
    }
    return this.asset
  },
  string: function(e) {
    return e
  }
});
SqueezeBox.handlers.url = SqueezeBox.handlers.ajax;
SqueezeBox.parsers.url = SqueezeBox.parsers.ajax;
SqueezeBox.parsers.adopt = SqueezeBox.parsers.clone;
```

```css
/**
 * SqueezeBox - Expandable Lightbox
 *
 * Allows to open various content as modal,
 * centered and animated box.
 *
 * @version  1.3
 *
 * @license  MIT-style license
 * @author  Harald Kirschner <mail [at] digitarald.de>
 * @author  Rouven Weßling <me [at] rouvenwessling.de>
 * @copyright Author
 */

#sbox-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
#sbox-window {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 10px;
  /* invalid values, but looks smoother! */
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#sbox-window[aria-hidden=true],
#sbox-overlay[aria-hidden=true] {
  display: none;
}
#sbox-btn-close {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  right: -15px;
  top: -15px;
  background: url(../images/modal/closebox.png) no-repeat center;
  border: none;
}
.sbox-loading #sbox-content {
  background-image: url(../images/modal/spinner.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
#sbox-content {
  clear: both;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.sbox-content-image#sbox-content {
  overflow: visible;
}
#sbox-image {
  display: block;
}
.sbox-content-image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.sbox-content-iframe#sbox-content {
  overflow: visible;
}
/* Hides scrollbars */

.body-overlayed {
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* Hides flash (Firefox problem) and selects (IE) */

.body-overlayed embed,
.body-overlayed object,
.body-overlayed select {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#sbox-window embed,
#sbox-window object,
#sbox-window select {
  visibility: visible;
}
/* Shadows */

#sbox-window.shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.sbox-bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 33px;
  height: 40px;
}
.sbox-bg-n {
  left: 0;
  top: -40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(../images/modal/bg_n.png) repeat-x;
}
.sbox-bg-ne {
  right: -33px;
  top: -40px;
  background: url(../images/modal/bg_ne.png) no-repeat;
}
.sbox-bg-e {
  right: -33px;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(../images/modal/bg_e.png) repeat-y;
}
.sbox-bg-se {
  right: -33px;
  bottom: -40px;
  background: url(../images/modal/bg_se.png) no-repeat;
}
.sbox-bg-s {
  left: 0;
  bottom: -40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(../images/modal/bg_s.png) repeat-x;
}
.sbox-bg-sw {
  left: -33px;
  bottom: -40px;
  background: url(../images/modal/bg_sw.png) no-repeat;
}
.sbox-bg-w {
  left: -33px;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(../images/modal/bg_w.png) repeat-y;
}
.sbox-bg-nw {
  left: -33px;
  top: -40px;
  background: url(../images/modal/bg_nw.png) no-repeat;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .body-overlayed {
    overflow: visible;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 979px) {
  #sbox-window {
    overflow: none;
  }
  #sbox-btn-close {
    right: -10px;
    top: -10px;
  }
}
@media (max-device-width: 979px) {
  #sbox-content {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  #sbox-content.sbox-content-iframe {
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="../massmail.php" method="post">
  <label>Periode:</label>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <input class="form-inline input-small" name="maand" type="text" placeholder="bijv.: juni" />
    <input class="input-mini" name="jaar" type="text" value="2015" />
  </div>
  <br />
  <label>Inleidende tekst:</label>
  <div>
    <textarea name="inleiding" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>
  <br />
  <label>url van de nieuwsbrief:</label>
  <div>
    <input class="input-xxlarge" name="link" type="url" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Verzenden</button>
    <button class="btn" formaction="../voorbeeld.php" formmethod="get" type="submit">Voorbeeld</button>
    <a href="index.php">
      <button class="btn" type="button">Annuleren</button>
    </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is now solved.
I have used the second line (working popup).

```
<a class="btn modal" href="voorbeeld.php" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 920, y: 530}}">Voorbeeld</a>
```

As mentioned this does open the popup, but it doesn't seem to process the form, so I deleted the button inside the `<a>` which was supposed to process the form but didn't send it to the popup.

I have then fetched the form data with Javascript by using:

```
var id = window.parent.document.getElementById('id').value;
```

For this to work, all the form elements you want to use in the popup have to have an id.

Hope this helps anyone stumbling upon this.